# oracle regular expression - search for a particular string

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a data in a column like this

```
Test 20019-2000 test
Test 119 test
Test 19-EM
Test EM - 19
```

SO, when I do a `REGEXP_LIKE(mesage,'19')` it is retrieving all the 4 records. But my requirement is that , it should fetch the rows in which, the token string is starting with "19".

SO it should fetch 3 and 4th row only. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle regexp does not support the traditional word boundry operators `\b` or `\<`. But you can simulate this by matching the start of string OR a non-word character immediately before the `19`.

E.g. Here I define a word as being a sequence of alphanumerics. So you need

```
REGEXP_LIKE( mesage, '(\A|\W)19' )
```

Will match `19`, `fred 19`, `fred.19`, but not `fred19`. If you do want to define a word as being non whitespace, and thus not match `fred.19` change it to

```
REGEXP_LIKE( mesage, '(\A|\s)19' )
```